# Count Query Data From API

Tags: jquery

I have API from teamwork, I want to count my data where status is new

```
<script>
$(function() {   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.com/tasks.json',
        type: "GET",
        headers:{
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa('email@gmail.com:password')
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $.each(data['todo-items'], function(key, value) {
                if(value.status == "reopened"){
                    console.log(value.status.length)
                }
            })
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

that code has output 8, but my data if I count where status is new has 20 data

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. You've shown us that the AJAX request is working, but to help you filter the data we need to know exactly what `data` contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not counting the number of items.  Currently, you're logging the length of the `status` property (which is `"reopened".length == 8`).  But you can see the chrome console is actually logging the value 20 times.

You could create a `count` variable:

```
success: function(data) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(data['todo-items'], function(key, value) {
        if(value.status == "reopened"){
            count++;
        }
    });
    console.log(count);
}
```